# Ext JS: How to return xml from a php's curl call to extjs proxy in Store?

Tags: php, xml, extjs, proxy, store

I am new to ExtJs and web technologies, what I am trying to do for days is to get a response from my php file that makes a curl request to a servers api, and return a xml format object. When I store this object seperatly in a xml file and set the ExtJs store's proxy as

```
proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'app/apiCalls/data_suites.xml',
            autoload: 'true',
            autoSync: 'true',

            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                root: 'data_suites',
                record: 'data_suite'
            }
        }
```

..it load the data into the store, but when I change the proxy to the .php file that returns the same object, it fails to load the data.

this is my .php file with sample xml return:

```
$my_endpoint = XXXXXXX //myendpoint defined here

function curlCall($my_url){

    $header[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    //initializing curl object
    $curl = curl_init();
    //adding fields to the curl object to enter the site
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $my_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    //executing the curl call and getting data back
    $html = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl); // close the connection

    return $html;
}

$html = curlCall($my_endpoint);
echo $html;

//even tried returning as simple xml object but didnt work
//$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
//echo $xml
```

I only changed this line in my store proxy to try to receive the .php output

```
url: 'app/apiCalls/data_suites.php',
```

here is my sample "data_suites.xml" which is the same thing that my browser shows for the php return as $html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data_suites>
   <data_suite id="6">
      <name>Test</name>
      <description>Test Described</description>
   </data_suite>
   <data_suite id="8">
      <name>Another Test</name>
      <description>Another Test Described</description>
   </data_suite>
</data_suites>
```

Thank you, and let me know if things are not clear.

Comment: I even tried setting my proxy type as 'rest' but unfortunately no results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the header in your php script
Like this:

```
<?php
.
.
.
$html = curlCall($my_endpoint);
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Worked!!! I was missing this and also fixed a small syntax error on my php file! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set your response header to XML?

`header('Content-type: text/xml');` before `echo $html;`, because ExtJS's XML reader won't recognise the response as XML if it is sent with another content type.